# Trying to add all cookies together from a webrequest, but when I print it, it sends back system.net.cookiecontainer

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am struggling getting a cookie, from a website, when I alert the cookie,it just returns: `system.net.cookiecontainer` Here's how I am trying to get the cookie:

```
'get the cookie for the post request !important
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html"), HttpWebRequest)
req.Method = "GET"

'iniate the cookie container for the post request
Dim tmpcookie As New CookieContainer

'get the cookie.
Dim postcookie = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
tmpcookie.Add(postcookie.Cookies)
'assign the cookie to use outsie the scope (background worker)
textcookie = tmpcookie.ToString()
```

but when I alert textcookie I get what I said above :(

Answer (score 0):

`tmpcookie` is a `CookieContainer`. You're calling `ToString` on a `CookieContainer`, it does what it's specified to do: output the fully qualified type name, "System.Net.CookieContainer".

It's like doing `(New List(Of Object)).ToString()` - it's going to output "System.Collection.Generics.List", not a string representing every item in that list.

You'll want to iterate the cookies in that container, and concatenate/build (?) a string from each individual cookie in that container.

Comment: I've tried looping through cookie container, but it displays nothing:

Comment: For Each tempCookie As Cookie In postcookie.Cookies
                MessageBox.Show(tempCookie.Name)
            Next

but the message box doesn't show.

Comment: And exactly what type is `postCookie.Cookies`? You need to fix the pluralisation of your variables (naming in general), they're confusing. At the end of the day the reason `CookieContainer.ToString` is displaying the name of the type is exactly what my answer says.